Vegetative propagation of Drosera burmannii
Is it possible to propagate Drosera burmannii vegetatively by using leaf, flower, or root cuttings? If so, how? It seems that D. burmannii is commonly cultivated from seed. I could not find instructions to do vegetative reproduction.

Just had a look at some pictures and D. burmannii forms a compact rosette of short, rounded leaves with no petiole. A successful leaf cutting requires enough totipotent axillary bud tissue to be attached to the leaf in order for new plants to form, and i suspect it's almost impossible to get a viable leaf cutting from it without dismantling the whole plant to do so. Also, D. burmanni reproduces via seeds only and does not produce tubers or rhizomes, the roots are not totipotent and neither are the flowers or flower stalks.
